# JS beforeunload not working on window.addEventListener('beforeunload', (evt){})

Tags: javascript

I tried it on Chrome and Safari, neither browser works。Only one alert window in Chrome as below when I refreshed the page. If only evt.preventDefault() was used, the function didn't work.  I don't know whether it and .returnValue need to be used together.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hae5F.png)

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload',(evt)=>{
//evt.preventDefault();
let confirmationMsg = "Are you sure to quite?";
(evt || window.event).returnValue = confirmationMsg; 
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should use both together.  Chrome still requires `.returnValue` to be set, but the HTML specification states that you should use Event.preventDefault() instead of a return value.
This is an issue of non-conformance to the standard on Chrome's part.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload#Example

At the bottom they have detailed description of the state of `beforeunload` support in some of the more popular browsers.